# My main logo banner appears in my Navbar when I scroll

Tags: html, css, navbar

I've given my navbar a fixed position and a z-index of 1. It stays at the top when I scroll which is good, but then my logo doesn't go behind it as it scrolls up, it can still be seen in the nav area which I really don't want. Below is the css for my Logo. I'm still learning web design. Thanks.

```css
#logo {
    background-color: #292421;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding: 40px 0 25px;
}
#nav_bar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: url(..images/header-fade.gif) repeat-x;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: What's the style for the `navBar`? What's the `HTML`? Good idea would be also to provide us an example code, using e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: post your html please

Comment: #nav_bar {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 background: url(..images/header-fade.gif) repeat-x;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

Comment: I updated your question with the CSS from your comment. Please provide us some HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#nav_bar` has no background. The URL you provided is incorrect. You probably wanted it to be

```css
background: url(../images/header-fade.gif) repeat-x;
```

Notice that you missed slash character `/` after the dots `..`

Comment: Thanks so much, that's sorted it!